# pl/sql trigger integrity constraint issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I was tasked to create triggers to insert into a log table when an order table was

1. Inserted into
2. updated

also insert/delete/update was to be disabled between 5pm friday and 9am monday. The solution that follows covers all this, however because it is a before trigger I have had to turn off integrity constraints (does this matter for a log table?)

Does anyone have any suggestions how I might be able to do this AND keep the integrity constraints (on the logono column)?

I was thinking about 11G compunt triggers but it was sugegsted in a previous answer that this would not be an appropriate use, plus the issue with backwards compatibility.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_order
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE out_of_hours EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
IF
 TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DHH24' ) ) BETWEEN 109 AND 517 THEN 


    insert into order_log values
 (order_log_PK.nextval, 
 (select user from dual), 
 :NEW.ono, 
 (select  SYSDATE from dual), 
 'Order Inserted' ) ;
ELSE
    RAISE out_of_hours;
END IF;
END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN 
IF
 TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DHH24' ) ) BETWEEN 109 AND 517 THEN 


    insert into order_log values
 (order_log_PK.nextval, 
 (select user from dual), 
 :NEW.ono, 
 (select  SYSDATE from dual), 
 'order updated' ) ;
ELSE
    RAISE out_of_hours;
END IF;
END IF;
IF DELETING THEN
IF 
 TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DHH24' ) ) BETWEEN 109 AND 517
 THEN 
RAISE out_of_hourS;
END IF;
END IF;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN out_of_hours THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('there is not privelages at this time');
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'CANNOT UPDATE OUT OF HOURS');
END;
```

thanks

**EDIT**

The integrity issue came about becaue the :NEW.ono value going into the Log Table is not yet inserted into the order table due to this being a before trigger, therefore violating the logono Foreign Key.

Comment: What integrity constraints did you need to disable?  I'm not sure that I follow what made that necessary.

Comment: When inserting the :NEW.ono into the log table because it is a before trigger there is no reference to it yet in the order table so the FK in the log table was causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your trigger so that you only check the Monday 9am - Friday 5pm condition once, so that you only have one place where you insert into the log table, and to eliminate the need for an extra exception and an exception handler.

You can make the trigger an AFTER INSERT trigger so that the trigger executes after the data already exists in `ORDERS` so that you could create a foreign key constraint in `ORDER_LOG` that references the `ONO` key in `ORDERS`.  However, it would seem very odd to want to create that sort of constraint.  If you create your log table as a child of the base table, that would mean that you either would never be able to delete a row from `ORDERS`, since there would always be a child row, or that you would need to delete all the rows from `ORDER_LOG` for that `ONO` before doing the delete.  Neither of those is generally particularly desirable-- in general, the point of having a log table is that it will log all the operations, not just the operations on rows in the base table that are still present.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_order
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON orders
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  l_operation varchar2(30);
BEGIN
  if to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'ddhh24' ) ) between 109 and 517
  then
    if inserting
    then
      l_operation := 'Order inserted';
    elsif updating
    then
      l_operation := 'Order updated';
    end if;

    -- Note that I'm guessing at the names of the columns in order_log
    insert into order_log( order_log_pk, 
                           modify_user,
                           ono,
                           modify_date,
                           description )
      values( order_log_PK.nextval,
              user,
              :new.ono,
              sysdate,
              l_operation );
  else 
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Cannot update out of hours' );
  end if;
END;
```

While it may be syntactically valid to do an `INSERT` into a table without listing the columns you are inserting into, doing so is dangerous.  If you add another column in the future, even if it is not required, your `INSERT` will start failing.  If you list the columns explicitly, the trigger will continue to work.  It is also relatively hard to spot bugs where data is being inserted into the wrong column if you don't list the columns explicitly.  I guessed at what the columns were-- you'll have to substitute the proper column names.

Comment: Brilliant stuff. Do you see any argument for the date check to be done in a compltely seperate trigger?

Comment: @DylanJackson - I wouldn't put it in a separate trigger but I would strongly consider putting it in a separate procedure that is called from the trigger.  I'm not personally a fan of collapsing the date check into a single line of code like this, it's too easy to miss a corner case.  I would rather be more verbose in this case because it's easier to see what's going on and to mentally verify that it works as expected.  For example, the check as written actually allows updates between 5pm and 5:59:59pm on Friday.

Comment: Yes, I can see this now you point it out! Time to revisit my previouse question with regards to that then. Thankyou.